# Getting error while creating a new Project

Tags: react-native

I'm new to reactnative. I have followed steps to install reactnative properly but, while creating a new project, I'm getting an error. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit with i3 processor.

```
c:\ReactNativeProjects>react-native init AwesomeProject
```

> Command npm install --save --save-exact react-native failed.

My Folder contains only one file 
[image: My Folder contains only one filee]
[image: Getting Error in cmd]

Answer (score 0):

These are my steps to get rid of this error:

1. Please upgrade your npm

> npm install -g npm@latest

2. Run npm cache clean command in Command prompt ( With some element of doubt for cache presence)

3.Ran react-native init in command prompt as Administrator (on Windows OS), hoping works well with sudo react-native init on Mac OS

If still problem persist make sure that you have followed each and every step mentioned in Documentation i.e. installed JDK, PYTHON, NODE.
Refer to this link [For windows](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#installing-dependencies-3)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, But Still not working, See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting to use React Native, consider using [Expo](https://expo.io/), I've used it and it makes developing, debugging, testing and deploying to the apple store and google play easier.

According to the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html):

> Expo is the easiest way to start building a new React Native
>   application. It allows you to start a project without installing or
>   configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or Android
>   Studio installation required (see [Caveats](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#caveats)).
>
> Assuming that you have Node installed, you can use npm to install the
>   Expo CLI command line utility:
>
> `npm install -g expo-cli`
>
> Then run the following commands to create a
>   new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":
>
> `expo init AwesomeProject`
>
> `cd AwesomeProject`
>   `npm start`
>
> This will start a development server for
>   you.

I've [answered a question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048517/1042409) for the steps and what happens when you build your `.apk` and `.ipa` files using Expo, have a look at that as well.